# R Plotly Stacked Bar breakout date not in correct order

Tags: r, plotly, stacked-chart, breakout

I have an R plotly stacked bar chart where it's broken out by date.  I am trying to change the order from the oldest date 10/1/2020 to the newest date 01/01/2021 on top.  I noticed in the current state that it's not even in the correct order of dates. The data frame shows in the correct order.

The current code I have.

```
 ramp2 <- colorRamp(c("deepskyblue4", "white"))
 ramp.list2 <- rgb( ramp2(seq(0, 1, length = 15)), max = 255)
 plot_ly(pcd_2,
         x = ~reorder(u_reason_code,-total_qty, sum), y = ~total_qty, type = 'bar', color = ~month_breakout ) %>%
   layout(list(title = 'Cost'), barmode = 'stack') %>%
   layout(colorway = ramp.list2) %>%
   config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try with pcd_2[order(as.Date(pcd_2$month_breakout, format="%d/%m/%Y")),]

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me. Duck's answer ended up working for me.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formating your date as factor with next code (not tested as no data was shared):

```
#Process data
pcd_2$Date <- as.Date(pcd_2$month_breakout,'%m/%d/%Y')
pcd_2 <- pcd_2[order(pcd_2$Date),]
pcd_2$month_breakout <- factor(pcd_2$month_breakout,
                               levels = unique(pcd_2$month_breakout),
                               ordered = T)
#Plot
ramp2 <- colorRamp(c("deepskyblue4", "white"))
ramp.list2 <- rgb( ramp2(seq(0, 1, length = 15)), max = 255)
plot_ly(pcd_2,
        x = ~reorder(u_reason_code,-total_qty, sum), y = ~total_qty, type = 'bar', color = ~month_breakout ) %>%
  layout(list(title = 'Cost'), barmode = 'stack') %>%
  layout(colorway = ramp.list2) %>%
  config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding decreasing=True to the order line.                                                     
pcd_2 <- pcd_2[order(pcd_2$Date, decreasing=TRUE),]

Comment: @newbie_146 That is great! Nice job!